# how to assign variable from sub command?

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to generate a string and assign it to a variable that i would like to use in a later task.

tried reading through the documentation, but there aren't any examples of how to do this.

using `Bash@3`

doesn't work

```
      GITSHA=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD | cut -c1-10)
      echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=tag]$(1.0.0-${GITSHA})'
      echo $TAG
```

doesn't work

```
      GITSHA=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD | cut -c1-10)
      echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=tag]1.0.0-${GITSHA}'
      echo $TAG
```

doesn't work

```
      GITSHA=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD | cut -c1-10)
      echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=tag]"1.0.0-${GITSHA})"'
      echo $TAG
```

I expect there's a way to generate a value during the script and assign it using this mechanism so it can be used in downstream tasks.

Answer (score 1):

> how to assign variable from sub command?

Seems the syntax is incorrect.

Please try to below format:

```
GITSHA=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD | cut -c1-10)
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tag]1.0.0-$GITSHA"
```

Then the variable should be work in the next step, you can use command line to show it:

```
steps:
- script: |

   echo $(tag)
```

Besides, you can use command line task and run below commands to set the variable:

```
set GITSHA=(git rev-parse --verify HEAD | cut -c1-10)
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=tag]1.0.0-%GITSHA%
```